# How to add the effect of structual change points (level shift, local time trends, changes in seasonal pulses ) in ARIMA IN PYTHON?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, time-varying-covariate, structural-change

I am working on a time series forecasting problem.**As I came to know that I was not considering structural changes and seasonal dummies and was building a simple ARIMA that was causing a very poor fit**. I added monthly and day dummies and provided them as exogenous variable in seasonal ARIMA (SARIMAX) ,which improved the model somewhat.

[image]

with respect to the the ARIMA model-

[image]

**I want to ask how to add the effect of change points in ARIMAX/SARIMAX in python** and I also want to understand the conceptual understanding of **after adding these change points how does the cost function/parameter estimation of the of the model changes** ?

Comment: You say "I added monthly and day dummies and provided them as exogenous variable in seasonal ARIMA (SARIMAX) ,which improved the model somewhat." . I say "not so much" as there is no daily effect JUST day 1 and there are no level shifts in the out-of-sample so your level shifts make little sense and represent your specification for this problem. Cost function/parameter estimation is not a familiar statistical concept to me . Is it machine language speak ?

Comment: There is an effect for JUST 2 months of the year (september & october) based upon the first 413 values. It appears that you have inserted/assumed  a Jan/Feb effect

Comment: yes, I added a dummy for each month and provided them as exogenous variable. From the first comment - yes Cost function/parameter estimation is word from machine learning ,what I wanted to ask is the how adding the effect of different change points affects the model performance for future points(test points) , like for the exogenous variables I read that there is regression model with ARMA errors.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398489/how-to-predict-the-next-number-in-a-series-while-having-additional-series-of-dat/398496#398496 for stuff on the ARMAX model. The Model I developed for your data is an example of that